# What is the meaning of this kind of indexing [::-1] in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, indexing

I know that[:,-1] means in pandas to use every row element and the last column element.
But currently I see in the pandas documentation this one [::-1] and I wonder the meaning behind it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optional 3rd number in the `__getitem__` is the [`step`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/17554722). [For pandas dataframes and series](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#slicing-ranges), as with python lists, when the third value is -1, you get the items in reverse order. For example

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1], [2]])
# prints a row with 1, then a row with 2
print(df)
# prints a row with 2, then a row with 1
print(df[::-1])
```